# Add additional xml to websphere classpath

Tags: websphere-8, ibm-rad

I'm trying to add a xml file to my RAD9/Websphere 8.5 environment.   This is a third party xml and they advise to load the xml in the classpath and their library would automatically pick it up and parse it from the classpath.
I tried adding the xml to WEB-INF, WEB-INF/web-context, WEB-INF/classes, the folder where the java class makes the call to the api and the xml still doesn't seem to be available to the third party library.
I'm not sure if RAD9 packages the java project into a jar/war/ear on **Project->Clean** and if there is a setting I could tweak to include the xml file.

Comment: Where is located that 3rd party library? If it is in `WEB-INF/lib` then putting that xml file to `WEB-INF/classess` should work. For RAD to automatically place it in `WEB-INF/classess`, you should put that file directly into your `src` folder.

Comment: the third party libs are in WEB-INF/lib.   The xml is in the source folder from where the java api is called (and hence should make it to the classes folder), but its not accessible.

Comment: Add test servlet with `getResourceAsStream()` method call to see if your code can access that file. Maybe there is an issue with the library.